# How to get users' browsers to forget cached index.html file containing a refresh redirect?

Tags: php, html, apache, browser-cache, redirect

Have installed WordPress on a server which previously had an index.html file containing:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=home.html">
```

Now even though the index.html file no longer exists, my browser (and presumably the browsers for many users that have previously viewed the site) is still redirecting to home.html. The result of this is that WordPress gives a "Nothing Found" error when trying to view the website root (ie mysite.com redirects to mysite.com/home.html").

I've tried adding an Apache setting to the .htaccess file (as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509243/force-refresh-of-browser-cache-for-html-document)) but it didn't work. Possibly the Apache module is disabled. Not sure how to check. It's a cPanel site, and I may not be able to activate the module if it's not installed.

I also tried creating a home.html file that redirects to home.php, and the home.php contains:

```
<?php require_once("index.php");
```

However though the redirect worked, I still got a "Nothing found" error from WordPress. This may be due to the WordPress .htaccess settings (I could edit that if it would fix the problem).

Obviously clearing my browser cache will fix it for me, but I want a fix to implement on the site that will work for other users. Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: you could redirect back to `index.html?noonce` or some such just to force the browser not to show the cached version, at this point this largely up to the browsers when they want to clear cache.

Comment: Thanks @Victory I was just about to try that when I tried simply making home.html redirect to index.php and that seemed to work in my case. I can't be completely sure whether that is the best solution, as I don't have a complete understanding of Chrome caching, but it worked for me this time. Please feel free to add it as an answer, and I'll upvote it. I'll leave the question open a little while in case others can add further explanations though.

Answer (score 2):

The browser's cache is mostly out of your hands, but you can use a query string to force the browser to make another request.

For instance `home.html` could have

```
<script> document.location = '/index.html?noonce=1'; </script>
```

As suggested by @IMSop the Apache `mod_rewite` would be cleaner.

```
RewriteRule ^/home.html /index.php?nonce
```

Then you could use a canonical in your `index.html` so search engines know the correct url.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/" />
```

[google's page on canonical links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en)

Comment: Neater than a JS page would be an Aoache redirect for the same idea: `RewriteRule ^/home.html /index.php?nonce`